# named url is not recognized

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a named url in my template, but It's not working. I already tried changing the name of the url called in the template to `'progress'`, which is another url conf in `urls.py`. And it works fine. But when I change it to `UserSair`, it just crashes.

I'm getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'UserSair' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

in this line:

```
<a href="{% url "UserSair" %}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sair</a>
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap, FlatPageSitemap


sitemaps = {
  'site': Sitemap,
  'flatpages': FlatPageSitemap,
}



# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'quiz.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^quiz/', include('quiz.foo.urls')),


    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    ####################
    # quiz base url    
    url(r'^$', 'simulado.views.index'),

    # quiz category list    
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'simulado.views.view_category', name='view_quiz_category'),

    #django social auth
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),

    #notificacoes pagseguro
    url(r'^notif$', 'simulado.views.notificacao', name = "notif"),



    #  cart 
    url(r'^carrinho$', 'simulado.views.carrinho'),
    url(r'^buyItem$', 'simulado.views.buyItem', name = "buyItem"),


    #  obrigado, return from pagseguro 
    url(r'^obrigado$', 'simulado.views.obrigado'),



    #sitemaps
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',{'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),

    #  progress 
    url(r'^progress/$', 'simulado.views.progress', name = "progress"),
    url(r'^progress$', 'simulado.views.progress', name = "progress"),

    # logout
    url(r'^UserSair/$', 'simulado.views.sair', name = "UserSair"),
    url(r'^UserSair$', 'simulado.views.sair', name = "UserSair"),


    #  passes variable 'quiz_name' to quiz_take view
    url(r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)/$',
        'simulado.views.quiz_take'),  #  quiz/

    url(r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)$/',
        'simulado.views.quiz_take'),  #  quiz

    url(r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)/take/$',
        'simulado.views.quiz_take'),  #  quiz/take/

    url(r'^(?P<quiz_name>[\w-]+)take$',
        'simulado.views.quiz_take'),  #  quiz/take

)


urlpatterns += patterns("",
  url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 
      'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', 
      {'sitemaps': sitemaps}
  ),
)
```

And this is the view:

```
def sair(request):
    return render(request, 'quiz_index.html')
```

Comment: No, just the same error

Comment: First off, you have multiple urls with the same name.  There's no point to that.  use "/?" for an optional slash.  dont make an entirely new url pattern

Comment: what happens when you run reverse('UserSair') from the shell?

Comment: I can't find a relevant problem in your code.  It seems you're leaving something out, or you havent saved everything.  Can you post more of the traceback?

Comment: what version of django are you using? and dont forget to restart server after you make the changes in files other then templates

Comment: For checking just try and use `<a href="/UserSair">Sair</a>` and remove multiple urls with same `name`. Once this works go for the `{% url %}` tag

Comment: Just for reference about the trailing slashes:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: Thanks! oh, I feel very bad. I just restarted the server, and it's now working. My bad.